# system.security.NoAccessException when trying to save

Tags: apex, permissions, sharing

I have a big confusion here.

I have a visual force page with a custom controller. It has a save button that calls the save() action in the custom controller.

- Custom controller has "without sharing"
- My understanding is all Apex runs in System mode and does not respect user permissions.

I created a profile (Say Profile_1) with "Read only" access to an object (Say Object_1). If my understanding is right about Apex, the save() method should successfully insert the object for any user (even if he is from Profile_1_. But it did not. It failed for user from Profile_1 with the following error as banner message

> system.security.NoAccessException: Create access denied for Object_1

Once I gave "create" permission for Object_1 on Profile_1, it inserted successfully. What am I understanding wrong here? Without sharing should not make any difference here as its role and sharing rules related and not profile related.

Comment: Can you post the code of your save method? I'd only expect to see this behavior if you delegate to a standard controller.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this problem? I'm experiencing the same problem when trying to update a price book from a VF controller with a user whose profile doesn't have modify privileges on price book.

Comment: this could also be generated by the VF page. If you have an inputfield for any non-editable fields, even if you have the controller set to 'without sharing' it will raise an error on the VF page.